# adding input fields dynamically Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm building this form were the user can add input field dynamically by clicking the `+` sign.

Then the user can remove the previously added input by clicking the `-` sign.

My problem is when the user removes one field, all fields are removed. I believe it depends on the position of the `.field_wrapper`.

I've moved the `.field_wrapper` to various positions but nothing seems to work. Either way the previously added input is not removed or all inputs are removed.

Can someone advise me on what I'm missing.

here is a link to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dadihall/j5fz48k9/14/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var add_input_button = $('.add_input_button');
  var field_wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');
  var new_field_html = '<input name="title[]" class="form-control form-item type="text" value="" data-label="title" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_input_button" title="remove field">-</a>';
  var input_count = 1;

  //add inputs

  $(add_input_button).click(function() {
    if (input_count < max_fields) {
      input_count++;
      $(field_wrapper).append(new_field_html);
    }
  });

  //remove_input
  $(field_wrapper).on('click', '.remove_input_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    input_count--;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row field_wrapper">
        <label class="col-md-offset-1 col-sm-3 control-label" for="title">Title</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9 col-10">
            <input id="title" class="form-control form-item required" name="input_title[]" type="text" value="" data-label="title" />
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_input_button" title="Add field">+</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: is this better ? https://jsfiddle.net/Lwyk9j54/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because the `parent('div')` from the remove button is the `div` which holds *all* the content. The simple way to fix this would be to wrap the new input and remove link in its own `div`.

Also note that `add_input_button` and `field_wrapper` already contain jQuery objects, so you don't need to wrap them again. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var $add_input_button = $('.add_input_button');
  var $field_wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');
  var new_field_html = '<div><input name="title[]" class="form-control form-item type="text" value="" data-label="title" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_input_button" title="remove field">-</a></div>';
  var input_count = 1;

  //add inputs
  $add_input_button.click(function() {
    if (input_count < max_fields) {
      input_count++;
      $field_wrapper.append(new_field_html);
    }
  });

  //remove_input
  $field_wrapper.on('click', '.remove_input_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    input_count--;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row field_wrapper">
    <label class="col-md-offset-1 col-sm-3 control-label" for="title">Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9 col-10">
      <input id="title" class="form-control form-item required" name="input_title[]" type="text" value="" data-label="title" />
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_input_button" title="Add field">+</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```